# How to fit text in container in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `button` element and it has 1 character of text in it. The button element is being styled with css and its width and height is a percentage of its parent. How can I (using css) make that 1 character be bigger font size so that it fits exactly inside the button (maintaining aspect ratio). But it shouldn't touch the border, there should be some padding. Does anyone know how to do this? Something like `font-size:100%`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: I don't believe this can be done for an arbitrary container without setting the font-size to an absolute value (for example in pixels). If the container size is dynamic you'd have to use javascript to calculate the required font size.

Answer (score 0):

Em is used to multiply the font size in the element by it's parent font size
button style="font-size: 1 em;" 
This font size will be the same as its parent
button style="font-size: 1.5 em;" 
This font size will be the same and half as its parent 
button style="font-size: 0.5em;" 
This font size will be half the size as its parent

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp explains this